# What does Cannot read property 'append' of undefined error mean?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have Multiple buttons that when clicked add an item to a list. I'm trying to make it so that similar items will be one after the other. I'm trying to accomplish this by using JQuery.

These are my buttons:

```
   @foreach (var Dish in item.Dishes)
   {
     <button onclick="AddItem('@Dish.DishName','@Dish.Price',@Dish.DishId)">@Dish.DishName</button>
     }
```

My JQuery function:

```
function AddItem(Name, Price, ID) {
            ID = "Dish" + ID;
            var arr = document.querySelectorAll("#" + ID);
            if (arr.length = 0)
        {
                $(".order").append(
                    $('<li/>').attr("id", ID).addClass("list-group-item").text(Name).append(
                        $('<span/>').addClass("badge").text(Price)
                    ));
              
            }
            else {
                arr[0].append(
                    $('<li/>').attr("id", ID).addClass("list-group-item").text(Name).append(
                        $('<span/>').addClass("badge").text(Price)
                    ));
            }
            }
```

I'm getting an error that says:
**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'append' of undefined
at AddItem
at HTMLButtonElement.onclick**

I'm not understading what's undefined and why.

Any advice would be very helpful and if something isn't clear please ask.

Thanx in advance

Comment: The error means that the object you're trying to call `.append` on is undefined and that call is in the AddItem method.  The "what" is whatever is before `.append`  (in x.append it's x)

Comment: `if (arr.length = 0)` *probably* should be `if (arr.length == 0)` (or `=== 0`)

Comment: If you pop this in the console `var a = 1,x=[]; if (x.length = 0) a = 2; console.log(a);` - you'll see that `(x.length = 0) == false` when x is an array - so it's hitting the else and `arr[0]` is undefined as `arr.length == 0` - **this is all stated in the error** - all because you've put `=0` instead of `==0`.  Voting close as a typo.

Comment: thanx freedomn-m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not able to pull the information you are specifying. This could be due to misspelling, broken file structures, etc.

Answer (score 0):

**SideNote**

I suspect you have multiple elements with the same id - at least your code reads as if you expect there to be an array of elements with the same id - that is invalid HTML!

So `querySelectorAll()` makes no sense in combination with an `id`. there should never be more than one element with any given `id`.

**Problem:**

`arr` holds the first of your elements with the given id, and `arr[0]` returns the DOM element of that given jQuery element. `append()` does not work on that.

**Solution:**

You would #1 need to change your elements and HTML so that you have unique IDs (if that is the case i dont see your HTML code). And use a class instead of the ids to identify your elements.

Then use `var arr = $('.myNewClassInsteadOfId');` to select that array, and then `arr.first()` to get the first element in that array.